# Why are there so few English words that begin with the letter X?

Tags: etymology, orthography, consonants, pronunciation-vs-spelling

If one reads a lot of children's books, it is obvious that X is a real thorn in the side for those authors looking to have each letter of the alphabet represented in their books.  Most of them either cop out with *X-ray*, or they make up fake words.

My copy of the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary has only 3 pages devoted to X and with the possible of exception of *xeric¹* and *X-ray*, none of the words would be recognized as  common.

Why are there so few common words in English that begin with the letter X?

<sup>¹ *xeric* may not actually be that common since it is not recognized by the spellchecker in my browser</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure this question has legs. FWIW, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) says that at 0.034%, words starting with **Z** are *less common* than words starting with **X** (0.037%). One might ask why **T** (16.6%) is so popular as a first letter, when it's far less common than **E** overall (9% compared to 12.7%)

Comment: @FumbleFingers if you go by the pages in my Shorter OED, X is much less common than Z.  Furthermore, I am assuming that the percentages you list are for total words in the language.  Really none of the X words in my S OED would you use in everyday language, except for X-ray.  I think the T question is an interesting one, but I suspect that it has a different answer than this one.  If it didn't, it would really be interesting!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the Wikipedia statistics are based on what fraction of words in a large corpus of texts start with some letter, whereas Kenny is looking what fraction of unique words start with some letter.

Comment: @Kenny: Yes, it seems very likely to me that X-words are *on average* more obscure than Z-words. It's not in alphabetical order, so this [5000 most common words](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm) isn't easy to check, but I doubt there are *any* X-words there (although come to that, there might not be any Z-works either).

Comment: @nohat: Oh. I didn't realise that. Ty.

Comment: @FumbleFingers fwiw, it has 'zone' but no X words. The original source of that data is http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y which has it in alphabetical order too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Checking was easy: 'View Source' and search for ">x" (the words are in an ordered list, so they look like this: <li>the</li>).  No hits found.

Comment: What about `xenophobia`? Or do they not do that where you're from?

Comment: @Jonas not very often, and not since 1903 or so. Before then they'd been getting by with being chauvinistic for the half-century or so before.

Comment: What about `Xmas`? :-) http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Xmas

Comment: Shel Silverstein wrote in "The ABZ Book" that "X is for xylophone, because X is always for xylophone."

Comment: I'd use xenophobe in ordinary speech. How about Xerox?

Comment: @DominicCronin  I use both too; but not when talking to a kid at the age alphabet books are written for.

Comment: @DanNeely The question doesn't restrict itself to children's language.

Comment: @ChristianDavén I know you're no doubt well aware of this and were joking, but for the record (considering the purpose of the site), I'll note that Xmas is actually Χ-mas where the Χ is a Greek chi, not a Latin X, and that Χ has been an abbreviation of Χριστός (Christ) since before even Old English existed, especially combined with the letter rho (Ρ) to form the Chi Rho (☧) the monogram of Christ which was a Christian symbol as far back as the days when Christians would have viewed the cross like we would a gallows or electric chair.

Comment: I just noticed that I pronounce the name Xavier as Ksavier, and not Exavier, or Zavier.

Comment: *"Most of them either cop out with X-ray, or they make up fake words."* - Really? None of the early reading books I used with my daughter made up X words. Why would they when *xylophone* is available?

Comment: @nnnnnn Indeed, and when toy glockenspiels are often called xylophones?

Comment: This is a question about aberrant printing practices -- technology -- rather than English language or usage. Spelling has no more connection to English than religion does to roses.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your dictionary goes further than Johnson's, for which the entire chapter for X was thus:

> X Is a letter, which, though found in Saxon words, begins no word in the English language.

And actually, it's not found in that many Saxon words. *Saxon* itself was one exception; *Seaxe* in Anglo-Saxon, as was the *seax*, the knife from which they took their name. (The Old High German equivalent was *Sahsun* though, the X wasn't shared with all their neighbours).

While the Latin alphabet adapted (with the addition of Ƿ Þ & Ð and the promotion of Æ from digraph to letter in its own right) for English use had an X, and before that the Anglo-Saxon Futhorc had ᛉ, the ancestor of the Futhorc, the Elder Futhark, had no such rune. [Rect: It had the rune ᛉ, but for a different sound].

So X it would seem was a bit of a novelty. It's also mainly used for a sound that cannot start a syllable in English. Notably, some English words that do start with X come from Greek words that do start with that sound (from Ξ rather than from Χ) get pronounced as do those beginning with *Z*. These words are also mostly relatively recent imports. (Though Χ is where X originates it has a sound that gets imported into English with the hard CH of *Christ* or is changed further).

There was a brief period of spelling words that begin with *sh* or *sch* with an X in some areas (*xal* as a spelling of *shall*), but it didn't catch on.

So, while it was in the English alphabet from the beginning, it wasn't in the alphabet before it, and it was used for a sound that English never uses at the start of a word.

This doesn't give that much of a *why*, since we can still ask why we don't have the same sounds as Greek, and why the Germanic languages didn't have them to begin with, but that goes beyond what I know on the matter.

I think it can be interesting for analogy to look at the influence of English upon Irish and Scottish Gaelic in relation to the word *vote*; In both cases in seeing the need to have such a word, and lacking a letter V, the Irish imported the letter and produced *votáil*, while the Scottish adapted their existing *tagh* (to choose or select). It could have gone differently (the Irish have *togh* related to *tagh*), people speaking either language may argue about whether it is better to import or adapt, but it went the way it did.

And here we're seeing from the outside what happened to English with such Greek words. It could have adopted Greek words that begin with Ξ more directly (learning how to pronounce the sound, instead of changing your *xeric* example among others) and earlier (so we'd have more such words), and more often, but it didn't.

(I'm sure there are other possible sources of X-words, but I don't know them).

And so, what X-starting words we have are more recent adoptions from Greek, recent coinages, and *X-ray* that use it as a symbol (it comes from the use of X for an unknown quality).

Edit: It's worth noting that we could easily do without X (a fact which makes it useful in languages only recently written in Latin script - you can press gang X into anything that doesn't fit the existing set of letters without much loss). Of course, various alphabet and spelling reformers have said that of other letters, and that makes it no more likely to happen, but we actually did with *connexion* which while still sometimes spelt that way is more often found today as *connection*. Noah Webster argued for the latter "for the sake of regular analogy, I have inserted connection, as the derivative of the English connect, and would discard connexion." which in a way was the invention of a new word by deriving from *connect* which happened to have the same meaning and pronunciation as the existing *connexion*. (*Connexion* was not derived from *connect* though they did have their roots in derivatives - indeed we briefly had both *connex* as well as *connect* but it died out, compare the long coexistance of *jail* and *gaol*).

In a way, therefore, it's as remarkable that we have as many words with X (though not at the beginning) as we do. Various words from the **laks* Indo-European root for *salmon*, for example come in with an X where the source does not: We have *lox* though the original Yiddish is often transcribed *laks*. While the X in our *gravlax* isn't unheard of among the Scandanavian sources (*gravad lax* in Swedish, *graflax* in Icelandic) some others did fine without it (*gravlaks* in Norwegian, while the Danes use both that and also *gravad laks*). When it appears in Viking-originated placenames in Ireland and Scotland an X is used in the Anglicisation though it isn't in the Irish or Gaelic (*Leixlip* is *Léim an Bhradáin* in Irish, *Laxdale* is *Lacasdal* in Gaelic - happily moving away from the KS sound the Vikings used entirely).

In all, it seems that while we would not go quite as far as Christopher Robin, who noted that the environs of Winnie the Pooh's house included "Big stones and rox", our instincts haven't been that far off his, at least until the 19th Century, when poor *connexion* began to get it in the neck.

So since so many of our neighbours, linguistically, make less use of it, it's as much of a curiosity that we do use X as often as we do.

Comment: Yiddish isn't written in the Latin alphabet, so its word for salmon couldn't be spelled with an "X" even if it wanted to be.

Comment: @Max Ah. I thought there was an agreed transcription method for romanising. Have edited to adjust rather than remove, because I've still seen "laks" rather than "lax", but stand ready to edit further if it turns out there's a heavy use of the latter. (I'm more a gravlax eater than a lox eater, so what would I know?).

Comment: There are standardised romanizations, and indeed most (all) of them use "ks", but that's partly because there's no single *Hebrew* letter for /ks/

Comment: The Russian write for Alexander: Aleksander.

Comment: @Max if "ks" is more common, I'm happy I wasn't going down a totally incorrect line of thought.

Comment: @DohnJoe or *Александр*, though that (along with Max's point) doesn't make this irrelevant. On the contrary, different possible decisions as to how to transcribe from non-Latin scripts (esp. Greek) is a big part of this whole topic.

Comment: In your paragraph about *vote* you use *adopted* and *adopt* rather than *adapted* and *adapt*. This stood out to me since *adopt* and *import* feel very similar to me in this context. I feel that *adapt* might be more appropriate.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thanks, *adapt* is indeed what I meant and *adopt* is indeed inappropriate and could in fact have been used where I use *import* were it not that it would clash with the - now corrected - *adapt*.

Comment: Cf. Irish *tacsaí*, which also avoids this letter.

Comment: @TRiG yes, while the language may have ended up importing the letter V for some loan words, not importing X is really easy, to the point where I'd say most people who have no Irish (and my own Irish is useless so I just have the few words that are often borrowed into Hiberno-English) could figure out what it meant, even if it isn't most often seen written on top of the very thing it describes. Avoiding X is so easy, that the fact English doesn't is another curiosity of it's own, but then the Saxons did have it in their own name, and they did love their seaxes.

Answer (score 38):

I don't have any proof, but a big clue to me is that the letter X in the default case represents the sound sequence /ks/, which is not a valid onset according to [the rules of English phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Phonotactics). That is, spellings of words don't start with X because pronunciations of words don't start with /ks/.

All the words that do start with X have an exceptional pronunciation—one where the letter X doesn't correspond to the pronunciation /ks/. In the case of X-ray, the pronunciation derives from the name of the letter rather than the sound the letter ordinarily makes. All the others are words borrowed from other languages, usually Greek, which aren't very common in English.

Comment: A more interesting question might be why we have virtually zero words ending in *q*. Or why *qu* is our go-to method for making the "kw" sound. Blog it!

Comment: Doesn't anyone play the xylophone anymore?

Comment: @aaamos  Indeed they do; my son does. But that's a word of Greek derivation, and the X is pronounced as /z/.

Comment: @StoneyB - Yes, but I suspect aaamos was struck - as I was - by the fact that the OP mentions 'xeric' (definitely NOT common) but not 'xylophone', which is still not terribly common but much more likely to come up.

Comment: @MT_Head: xelactly!

Comment: Yes, and while *xylophone* is very modern, *xeric* is from the 1920s!

Comment: xylophone indeed!  I am an ecologist so xeric is familiar but somehow xylophone slipped by me, despite having just read about a _xylophone car_ in a Richard Scarry book!

Comment: @aaamos, probably only xenophobes

Comment: @aaamos: Actually, yes – although perhaps not as often as one might think. (My daughter is a percussionist; she and her friends will correct me if I say "xylophone" when I should have said the more correct "bell kit" or "marimba" instead.)

Comment: @StoneyB Maybe I'm weird, but I do try to pronounce words starting with x as /ks/. It maddens me when I hear Xavier as 'eks-avier'. Maybe he should be called 'has a new house'!

Comment: @JohnFerguson  Well, Xavier should be pronounced with a /h/ ... but the established thing with Greek-derived initial *Xs* is /z/.

Comment: @J.R. We percussionists have few opportunities to exhibit our superior knowledge, so we leap at every opening.

Comment: I find it bizarre that people are arguing over how names "should" be pronounced.  Certainly it is reasonable to say that a name has "traditionally been pronounced as" such and such...but to say that someone is pronouncing their own name wrong strikes me as a bit narrow minded.

Comment: @aaamos Not since Sir Patrick Moore died.

Comment: @J.R. They are different instruments.  Whether you use that as rhetorical ammunition, I leave to your parental judgement.   (Of course, if she knows this already, this information will likely be of no use to you.)

Answer (score 9):

In the middle of an English word, like axe, the letter x denotes the consonant pairing *ks*.

There are no words in English which begin with the *ks* phonemes. The reason is simply "just because": English *morphology* does not manifest a leading *ks* and that is that.

Since English words do not have that sound at the beginning, that explains why there aren't any words which are written starting with *x* or *ks*. At least, not any words that originate in the English language.

Words that are written beginning with *x* are usually foreign loanwords (which perhaps **do** have the *ks* sound in their original language). Even if they originate in the English-speaking world, they have foreign roots (for instance *xanthan gum*, named after the *Xanthomonas campestris* bacterium by its discoverers at the U.S. Dep't of Agriculture).

When English adopts foreign loan words, there is usually a practice of maintaining the foreign spellings, but modifying their pronunciation to match whatever is suggested by their spelling as if it were English. So for instance *Pythagoras* becomes pie-THA-g'-rus, which is unrelated to the original Greek sounds. Various X words from Greek and other languages take on a leading Z sound: Xylophone becomes ZAI-lo-fone, and so forth, as English speakers intuitively avoid the forbidden leading *ks*. There is no reason to use X to write an English word which begins with the Z sound, except to preserve its foreign spelling.

Of course the pronunciation of words like *X-ray* (or *X-[anything]*) and *Mr. X* just spells the letter.

Comment: I don't agree that the reason is "just because". It (or *they* if there are several reasons) may or may not be unknown, but they aren't "just because".

Comment: Initial consonant clusters in English are always `Sibilant` + `Stop`. Initial `Stop` + `Sibilant` clusters like /ps/, /ts/, or /ks/ are forbidden. The reverse is normal at the end of a syllable, which is where **<X>** appears.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you have anything on the history that led to that being the case? It's the big gap in my own answer IMO, and really, the one that gets to the crux of the matter.

Comment: The historic perspective may be interesting to you, but it's not the crux of the matter at all. Some people are satisfied with the explanation which connects writing with morphology and importation of foreign loanwords, in the present language as it stands.

Comment: It's a general phonological universal. Normally sonority increases towards the nucleus vowel in the syllable, reaches a peak and declines. That's the canonic (though far from the only) way to delimit syllables; again, this varies a lot from language to language. Languages like Japanese, for instance, allow **no** phonemic initial consonant clusters of any kind, while in practice producing allomorphic clusters by devoicing high vowels between voiceless consonants.

Comment: Now *that* is interesting. And, with regard to your very last point there, speak of the devil, I was thinking about Japanese, in connection with this stackexchange question. The specific example I had in mind was: *kuso!* (shit, damn) may actually sound like *k'so*, giving us a Japanese word that starts with ks. :)

Comment: How is it not the crux of the matter to the question "Why are there so few English words that begin with the letter X?" to ask why there are zero English words that start with the sound represented by *X*. I could give a lot on the morphology in my answer, but it all leads back to that point.

Comment: @JohnLawler okay from the other side then, was is it that Greek does allow it?

Comment: It's not the crux because it's a separate question which has to do with linguistics in general and not with English: why do languages not use all the possible phonemes that humans can vocalize? And why do languages not allow all possible combinations of their chosen phonemes to be valid patterns for possible words? Hey wow, there is this now: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, dear, I can't possibly answer that in a comment, and it would take a whole bunch of answers to fantasy questions to deal with it. And I'm not a phonologist; I know what any linguist knows about phonological theory, but I really don't want to go farther than that. As to Greek, the history there is interesting, and I'll post an answer about that, by'n'bye. But it's not intended to contradict any of the other answers; they're already quite good.

Comment: @JohnLawler please do. I'd really like to read something on that part of it, and I don't have a good starting point to research it myself.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to the question of why so few English words start with *x* is that there are relatively few words starting with x (or ξ) in the main source languages from which English has borrowed words, word roots, and prefixes.

A check of the *x* entries in *Merriam–Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) indicates that the source languages for English words that begin with *x* and are neither proper names (such as *Xanadu* and *Xerox*) nor instances of *x* per se *x* (such as *x-axis* and *x-ray*) are very few. Greek gives us words based on *xanthos* (ξανθος, yellow), *xenos* (ξενος, host), *xeros* (ξερος, dry), *xiphos* (ξιϕος, sword), and *xylon* (ξυλον, wood). French from Arabic gives us *xebec* (a Mediterranean sailing ship). And Vietnamese from French gives us *xu* (a coin comparable to a sou).

Greek borrowings that begin with *x* are more numerous in English than in Latin, to judge from the skimpy number of such words included in *Cassell's Latin Dictionary* (1959/1968). That dictionary lists just five uncapitalized Latin words that begin with *x*: *xenium* ("a present given to a guest," from Greek *xenos*); *xerampelinae* ("dark-red garments," from Greek *xeros*), *xiphias* ("a sword-fish," from Greek *xiphos*), *xystici* ("athletes," from Greek *xustos* [ξυστος], "scraped, polished"), and *xystus* ("an open colonnade, a walk planted with trees, promenade" [also from from Greek *xustos*).

Do Latin and English demonstrate a systematic aversion to incorporating Greek words that start with *xi* (ξ)? Not really. Liddell & Scott, *An Intermediate Greek-English Dictionary*, seventh edition (1968) covers all of the Ancient Greek words that begin with ξ in just two and a half pages. This compares with three and a half pages devoted to entries beginning with ζ (zeta) and three and a half pages devoted to entries beginning with ψ (psi)—the only other letters that come close to challenging ξ as the least common word-starting letter in Ancient Greek.

In fact, I could find only a handful of distinct words starting with ξ in the *Intermediate Liddell & Scott* that don't appear in some form in at least one English word starting with *x* in the *Eleventh Collegiate*: ξαινω (*xaino*, "to comb or card wool"), ξεω (*xeo*, "to smooth or polish by scraping, planing, filing") ξουθος (*xouthos*, "yellowish, brown-yellow, tawny"), ξυνος (*xunos*, "common, public, general, concerning or belonging to all in common"), ξυρος (*xuros*, "a rasor"), and ξυστος (*xustos*, the "scraped, polished" term mentioned in connection with a couple of Latin words, and probably etymologically related to both the "smoothing" verb ξεω and the "rasor" noun ξυρος).

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps its because in the middle ages most people couldn't write, so signed their names as an X. Consequently a capitalised X at the start of a word could be confused as a signature?

--Edit--

Evdence that X was used as a signature exists. A quick google reveals:

http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/%22X%22+as+a+Signature

The rest is indeed speculation, hence the use of the word "perhaps".

Comment: Illiterate people (or those suffering a disability preventing legible writing) would have tended not to sign much, and tend to still figure out to sign at the point being pointed to, so it would no more have caused this problem than any other letter. O is a very common letter, but the comparable use of a circle by 19th & 20th C Jews in the US caused no such confusion. There was no comparable use of ᛉ as a signature when Anglo-Saxon was written in futhorc rather than Latin letters, and the lack of X dates back to before then.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this?  It seems rather speculative.

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: For that matter the literate would add Xs to signatures as well as their name (though a cross that became an X). That's not the hard to believe bit, but that a people's language would be influenced by a practice that came from a religion they didn't yet practice clashing with an alphabet they didn't yet use.

Comment: The illiterate "X" was not the letter - it was "his mark" - it did not have a pronunciation..