# Pterodactyl and Archeopteryx: Silent P vs Voiced P

Tags: roots, silent-letters

These words share the Greek root πτέρυξ (pteryx), meaning feather/wing, but the P in pterodactyl is silent (in the initial position), while the P in archeopteryx (in the middle of the word) is voiced.

Why is this, and what's the rule? Is it just that that's how the ancient Greeks pronounced it, or is there something more subtle going on?

Comment: NB: A voiced /p/ is a /b/. :)

Comment: Or in case you don't quite get what @tchrist means, *voiced* has a specific meaning when talking about pronunciation, with both *voiced* and *unvoiced* being heard. As he says, /p/ and /b/ are a voiced-unvoiced pair.

Comment: Darn. I knew that scrimping on my studies of Devanagiri would bite me some time...

Comment: Oh ptooey. It's hard to pick a best answer. +1 for everyone. I'm going to accept Jon Hanna's answer since he was first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Π (pi) in Greek is pronounced as P in English, and Τ (tau) in Greek is pronounced as T in English.

Greek though is quite okay with PT at the start of a syllable, while that isn't a phoneme cluster we have in English.

So, while we can pronounce both letters if we end one syllable with P and start the next with T, we will make the P silent at the start of a word.

This has happened for some time, since while *pterodactyl* is a relatively recent word, we've been talking about Ptolemy for quite some time.

Comparably, when we import  Ξ from Greek as X, we'll pronounce it KS in the middle of a word, but change to a Z sound at the beginning, as discussed at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102365/why-are-there-so-few-english-words-that-begin-with-the-letter-x).

Comment: Er, you wrote "\N{N-ARY PRODUCT} (pi) in Greek is pronounced as P in English, and \N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER TAU} (tau) in Greek is pronounced as T in English."  That is, you used U+220F N-ARY PRODUCT, whereas what you really wanted is U+03A0 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI, written Π — which while remarkably similar to ∏ in most fonts, is a different code point altogether.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist As well as being what I did indeed want, it's nicer looking in the font I'm seeing it in, too.

Comment: @tchrist you wrote "Er" whereas what you really wanted is "psst". I would also explain that N-ARY PRODUCT is not a letter. Its appearance will vary in web browsers and in other media where this open content (CC-BY-SA) answer may appear. But I see that it has been changed to GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI.

Comment: PT is not a phoneme in any language I've ever encountered. It's usually regarded as a cluster.

Comment: Thanks @ColinFine that is correct. Just muddled thinking on my part.

Answer (score 15):

First, the English rule has to do with syllable structure. As Colin points out, English syllables can't begin with the consonant cluster /pt/. Any word spelled that way will be pronounced some other way.

But the sequence /pt/ **can** occur between syllables. So if the vowel before /pt/ is stressed (as in *archeopteryx* /ar.ki.'ap.tər.ɪks/), then both stops can be pronounced, each in its own syllable, as Jon Hanna has noted. That's the English rule.

Of course, both words are made using the Greek word *πτέρυξ* (originally pronounced /'ptɛruks/) 'wing', and this word, as well as the English words *feather* (*p -> f* and *t -> θ* via Grimm's Law), *compete, perpetual, ptomaine, symptom*, and *hippopotamus*, all are descended from the PIE root **[*pet-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080624001150/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE405.html)** 'to rush, fly'.  The /p/ and the /t/ were **both** pronounced in Greek.

Finally, the English word *helicopter* is also transparently derived from *helico-* 'rotating, spiral' plus *-pter-* 'wing'. What's interesting about this is that *helicopter* is such a common word that it's been split into combining forms, but not the original ones.

In English, *helicopter* is divided into ***heli-*** (*heliport, helipad, helitaxi, helitours*, ...) and ***-copter*** (*cargo copter, minicopter, jetcopter,* ...), because the glue between *helico-* and *-pter-* wouldn't come off, but the glue between *heli-* and *-copter* turned out to be soluble in English phonology.

Comment: Very interesting point about the pseudoprefix "heli."

Comment: Nitpicking a little (okay, a lot), _πτέρυξ_ was never pronounced /ˈptεruks/. In Classical Greek, it would have been /ˈpteryks/ (with a close-mid /e/ rather than an open-mid /ε/—that was only found in η /εː/—and a round /y/). Even if the _-ks_ derivation, which came about within Greek itself, did exist before /u/ was rounded to /y/, that was before the Greek alphabet took form, so the word would more properly be _*pteruks_.

Comment: Not Classical; Homeric. Before Upsilon fronted.

Answer (score 10):

The trick is to get the two stops into separate syllables.  With *archaeopteryx*, the *p* ends one syllable and the *t* starts the next one.  With *pterodactyl*, no such luxury is possible, so the *p* is lost.

See also *apnea* versus *pneumonia*.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not how the ancient Greeks pronounced it: /pt/ was a possible initial cluster (as were /pn/, /ps/ and /kt/).

In English, /ps/ is a possible initial cluster (though it is rare, and pretty well confined to words of Greek origin) but /pt/, /pn/ and /kt/ are not possible initially, and get simplified (as does /kn/, which was possible in Old English).

All these clusters are normal medially, and generally split the consonants between syllables. Thus *uptake* and *archaeopteryx* contain /pt/ medially.

Comment: Probably because "pssst!" is possible. pssseudo, pssssylium, ... :) KN was possible in Old English? I did not kuh-now that! :)

Comment: @Kaz as was GN, HL, HN, HR and HW. GN and HW often leave their mark on modern spelling (the G of GN silent, and HW turned into WH), while the others generally don't (so *raven* and *lady* have lost their R)

Comment: @Kaz sorry, lost their H is what I meant to say.

Comment: Apart from “psst”, where is /ps/ a possible initial cluster in English? All _ps_-initial words (_psycho-_, _pseudo-_, _psalm_, etc.) begin with /s/ in all Englishes I’ve ever come across… Are there people who pronounce them with /ps/?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I've heard so, though I've never encountered one of them in person.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Maybe not. I certainly pronounce the name of the Greek letter Ψ with a /ps/ not a /s/.

Comment: True, there's _psi_, _ksi_, _Knesset_, _Tbilisi_, and such things. But those are more or less unassimilated foreign words that get to break phonotactics. (I also believe it's actually more common to pronounce ψ and ξ as /saɪ/ and /zaɪ/—that's certainly the only way I've heard them pronounced in American fraternity and sorority houses, which is the most common place I come across them spoken in isolation.)